# Anaconda - JupyterLab - spaCy : "No module named spacy" in terminal

Tags: anaconda, spacy

I'm using Anaconda and I'm trying to install spaCy.

At this point:
`python -m spacy download fr_core_news_sm`

I get stuck with the "no module named spacy" error.

Don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: If you're working with JupyterLab, make sure to install spacy and the model (fr_core_news_sm) in the same virtual environment the kernel is using.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install spaCy before you use it to download a model. You can use the [install helper](https://spacy.io/usage) to guide you on how to this, for example:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
python -m spacy download fr_core_news_sm
```